# how to add title icon (favicon) in amp-html

Tags: amp-html

I am trying these for adding title bar icon in amp project

```
<link href="/theme/images/favicon.png" rel="shortcut icon" type="image/png" />
```

OR

```
<link rel="icon" href="/theme/images/favicon.png">
```

Answer (score 4):

AMP does't have any specific requirement for adding general meta/link tags.

You can use: `<link rel="shortcut icon" type="image/png" href="/favicon.png">`

Make sure you add it in the `head` section and the `href` link is valid. You can also use **an absolute link** and see if it works.

Answer (score 3):

You can use an AMP page.

```
<link href="/YOUR_PATH/favicon.ico" rel="icon" type="image/x-icon" />
```

Answer (score 1):

You can simple use one or all of this:

```
<meta name="msapplication-square70x70logo" content="/images/shorts/small.jpg">
<meta name="msapplication-square150x150logo" content="/images/shorts/medium.jpg">
<meta name="msapplication-wide310x150logo" content="/images/shorts/wide.jpg">
<meta name="msapplication-square310x310logo" content="/images/shorts/large.jpg">
<link rel="apple-touch-icon" href="/images/shorts/apple-touch-icon-precomposed.png">
<link rel="apple-touch-startup-image" href="/images/shorts/splash-screen-320x460.png">
<link rel="shortcut icon" href="/favicon.ico" type="image/vnd.microsoft.icon">
<link rel="shortcut icon" sizes="196x196" href="/images/shorts/usa-196.png">
<link rel="apple-touch-icon" href="/images/shorts/apple-touch-icon-precomposed.png">
```

All tested and works fine. Keep care of the path to your favicon.